# Change the orientation of the edges in the root node in the twopi layout

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to figure out how I can switch between these two charts.
[image]
[image]

I am using the twopi layout.
I have tried various ways but I can't find the way it works.
someone can help me?

```
digraph G {

layout=twopi;

node [shape=circle]

0 -> 1
0 -> 2
1 -> 3
1 -> 4
2 -> 5
2 -> 6

}
```

Comment: Please add the code you used so it will be easier to advise.

Comment: @albert done :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to direct **twopi** to modify the node positions.  You could try adding invisible node & edges, but at best it would be a tussle.
Here is a (slightly modified) **gvpr** program that will take the original output and "rotate" (radially reposition) all the nodes around a specified node (your root).  [it is modified to avoid a bug in recent versions of **gvpr**]
**gvpr** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) is part of the **Graphviz** package, so you should have it.
The **gvpr** program: *rotateNew.gvpr*:

```
/* Given node name and angle, rotate a layout using the given
 * node as origin.
 */

BEGIN {
  double x,y;
  double x0,y0;
  double x1,y1;
  double angle, cosa, sina;
  int cnt, sz;

  void rotate (double a, double b) {
    a -= x0;
    b -= y0;
    x1 = a*cosa - b*sina;
    y1 = a*sina + b*cosa;
  }
  char* rotateE (char* p) {
    char* newpos = "";
    cnt = sscanf (p, "e,%lf,%lf%n", &x, &y, &sz);
    if (cnt == 2) {
      rotate (x,y);
      newpos = newpos + sprintf ("e%lf,%lf ", x1, y1);
      p = substr(p, sz);
    }
    cnt = sscanf (p, "s,%lf,%lf%n", &x, &y, &sz);
    if (cnt == 2) {
      rotate (x,y);
      newpos = newpos + sprintf ("s%lf,%lf ", x1, y1);
      p = substr(p, sz);
    }

    while (sscanf (p, "%lf,%lf%n", &x, &y, &sz) == 2) {
      rotate (x,y);
      newpos = newpos + sprintf ("%lf,%lf ", x1, y1);
      p = substr(p, sz);
    }
    print("// returning: ", newpos);
    return newpos;
  }
}

BEG_G {
  node_t ctr = node ($, ARGV[0]);

  sscanf (ARGV[1], "%f", &angle);
  print("// using >", ctr.name, "<   >", angle, "<");
  cosa = cos(angle);
  sina = sin(angle);
  print("// old pos: ", ctr.name, "  ", ctr.pos);  
  sscanf (ctr.pos, "%f,%f", &x0, &y0);
  print("// new pos: ", ctr.name, "  ", ctr.pos);  
  $.bb ="";
}
N {
  sscanf ($.pos, "%f,%f", &x, &y);
  rotate (x,y);
  print("// old pos: ", $.name, "  ", $.pos);    
  $.pos = sprintf ("%f,%f", x1, y1);
  print("// new pos: ", $.name, "  ", $.pos);  
}
E {
  // bug $.pos = rotateE($.pos);
  $.pos="";
}
```

Command line - two arguments provided w/ **-a** node_name & angle (in radians):

```
twopi myfile.gv |gvpr -cfrotateNew.gvpr -a "0 1.57" |neato -n -Tpng >myfile.png
```

More on what is going on with this set of programs: https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords

Result (note that the horizontal edges are short):
[image]

Comment: Hi @sroush, more than changing the node position I would like that the twopi layout to have the first two edges from the root starting east and west instead of north south. Anyway, I will try to take advantage of what you said. Thank you